# Dll not loading, method not resolved error on Win10

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I am referencing one managed C++ DLL which has native C++ as refernce in my c# code.
I am running it in VS 2019, Windows 10, when I run the program and after copying all DLLs in the build folder, I get error

**FILEIOException: A procedure imported by 'xxx.dll' could not be loaded,**

hence I am not able to debug anything.

If I just build my solution, and generated exe if I run in a machine with Window XP, it runs, also i installed VS2019 community on WinXP machine, it is also running properly.
Project target in .net4.5

What could be cause of dlls behaving this way?
Should I ask dll writer to create dll in VS 2019 only he is working on VS2010?

If exe is build on other machine and copied to Win10, it runs properly on Win10 machine.

I suspect some Visual Studio or dll issue but not able to figure out

Code is as below, there is one folder in all machines which have all dlls at particular loation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Initialize();
        InvokeLibrary();
    }

 static void Initialize()
        {
          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveAssembly);
        }

   static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolving Assembly....");

            String strDllName = "full path";

            Assembly MyAssembly1 = Assembly.LoadFile(strDllName);

            return MyAssembly1;
        }

static void InvokeLibrary()
        {
/// call functions in assembly
}
```

Comment: You may have to install the [Visual C++ 2010 runtimes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523), depending on how the unmanaged DLL was built.

Comment: @dxiv all C++ RT 2008 onwards are installed

Comment: Then look at `xxx.dll` with something like [depends](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what else is missing.

Comment: I installed VS community and ran project on it and it work fine, looks like VS professional issue